# How to replay to sender email from PHP instead of CGI-Mailer

Tags: php, email, header, cgi

I have tried too many different ways to get reply-to from the $_request[email] but it keeps sending the mails with the $from CGI- mailer, although all the body on my mail work´s fine..
I have tried too many ways but i can't find where is my problem..  i have looked at several answers to this question here but not any one fixes my problem.. this is my code.

```php
<?php
$subject = 'Contacact from website'; 
$to = 'contact@myhosting.com'; 
$emailTo = $_REQUEST['email'];

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email']; // i can't get this going to the reply-to section on the mail
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['message'];

$email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers .= 'From:  ' . $fromName . ' <' . $fromEmail .'>' . " \r\n" .
     'Reply-To: '.  $fromEmail . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Send email
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

$message .= 'Name : ' . $name . "\n";
$message .= 'Email : ' . $email . "\n";
$message .= 'phone : ' . $phone . "\n";
$message .= 'Message : ' . $msg;

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $email_from)) {
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo 'sent';
} else {
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

and this is my form:

```html
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action='email.php'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id='name_error' class='error'>write your name</div>
            <div>
                <input type='text' name='name' id='name' class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div id='email_error' class='error'>Write a valid email</div>
            <div>
                <input type='email' name='email' id='email' class="form-control" placeholder="
     email">
            </div>

            <div id='phone_error' class='error'>Write a phone number.</div>
            <div>
                <input type='tel' name='phone' id='phone' class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id='message_error' class='error'>Please write your message here</div>
            <div>
                <textarea name='message' id='message' class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Message or quotation"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p id='submit'>
                <input type='submit' id='send_message' value='Enviar' class="btn btn-line">
            </p>
            <div id='mail_success' class='success'>We received your message :)</div>
            <div id='mail_fail' class='error'>Please try again :/</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things wrong with what you posted.

Firstly, the first line for this block of code:

```
$message .= 'Name : ' . $name . "\n";
$message .= 'Email : ' . $email . "\n";
$message .= 'phone : ' . $phone . "\n";
$message .= 'Message : ' . $msg;
```

should not have a leading dot for `$message .=`, it should read as:

```
$message = 'Name : ' . $name . "\n";
```

Then this line:

```
if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $email_from))
```

Since you're using `$email_from` as the last argument, `mail()` as you did for the other instance where you are sending mail, is using a valid `From:` with an E-mail address as it's coming "from", when the 2nd one does not contain that, you only declared it as `$email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';`.

What you will need to do is add the `From:` as you did for the first mailing instance.

Side note: The `@` symbol is an error suppressor. You might want to remove that during testing/development.

Consult the manual on the `mail()` function for more detail:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php